# want to have single and double click on image in WP7 application

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I want to implement different functionalities for single and double click on image.
I was earlier using Manipulationstarted event .What could be used now?
I am using help from [click count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.clickcount.aspx)

but (e.ClickCount) is not supported

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the gestures in the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034)

e.g.:

```
<Image Source="filename.png" >
    <Controls:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Controls:GestureListener 
             Tap="GestureListener_Tap"
             DoubleTap="GestureListener_DoubleTap" />
    </Controls:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Image>
```

Beware that the tap event will always be called even when the double-tap event is also called. You could attempt to work round this by having a check in the tap event. (You'd need to have a short timer running on a different thread and if the double click isn't tirggered in this time then assume a double click.)

HOWEVER

From a usability point of view, you may make it easier on your users by having a tap event and a context (tap and hold) menu. This will make it much harder for the user to accidentally select the wrong option and it also gets rid of the problem above.

Having an object support both a tap (or click) and double tap event is not common because it's harder to discover or indicate to users and is easy to use the wrong action. Adding a context menu (right click menu on a PC) is the common convention for adding multiple options to users.

There is a `ContextMenu` also included in the Toolkit.

Comment: thanx for ur reply..But if double tap will first call single tap then my problem is not resolved since I wan to have two different functionalities on them.I just read somewhere that clickcounts can be done in MouseButtondown event.Is that possible?I tried but no success

Comment: @Shaireen If you just want to capture the double tap to make sure that you aren't missing any counts then simply have this do the same as a single tap. (You'll still get 2 "clicks" recorded on a double tap.) If you want to actually put some functionality behind the different events then this isn't the best way to do that.

Comment: Agree that you should be looking at tap + tap and hold, instead of click and double click - it'll be more consistent with both first and third party apps. Leave double click to PCs :)

Comment: I agree with Matt's comments regarding usability. I thought it would be cool to implement three behaviors with Tap incrementing a value by 10, Double Tap by 100 and Hold incrementing by 10 as long as the user keeps a finger down. People who tested it, including myself who was fully aware they were there, found the behaviors confusing until the Double Tap behavior was removed.

Answer (score 2):

Shaireen,

Check out my simple blog article here: [The simplest way to detect DoubleClick in Silverlight](http://yinyangme.com/blog/post/The-simplest-way-to-detect-DoubleClick-in-Silverlight.aspx).  That should give you the ability to detect both single Click's and DoubleClick's.

Good luck,
Jim McCurdy

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tapped event for single click and DoubleTapped event for double click in windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't have your own local counter variable.